# Has google increased apk limit from 50mb to 149?

Tags: google-play

I recently seen Angry Birds GO has apk size of 149 on google play, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsgo&hl=en

Yet google says apk size limit is 50 mb.So my question is,has google increased apk size limit from 50 mb?

Answer (score 2):

No, it hasn't.

According to the [development docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html):

> Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB

However, the same page mentions that you can have up to 4GB if you use expansion packs:

> You can provide up to 4GB of additional data for each APK

This is probably what Angry Birds GO uses.